# re-use jmeter recorded file but gives error

Tags: jmeter

I recorded google search step using jmeter. After finish recording I have save my recorded file but recorded steps are not readable:

[image]

Also I when I re-open that file and try to run this it gives error:
[image]

Anyone please help me on how can I run the recorded file

Comment: Can you please pose the HTTP Request default. You are using http, instead of https. Also you need to add google certificate in the safe zone in Internet Explorer settings.

Comment: Please click on this link for the HTTP Request default: http://screencast.com/t/FADEjuCjjzY

Comment: Did you reverse the browser proxy setting after recording and during running the jmeter tests?

Comment: Exclude unnecessary file types such as .png, .gif, .jpg, .js etc. during recording.

Answer (score 1):

'ocsp request' usually comes while recording with google chrome or when there is some google id running in back ground. you will not be able to see the values in plain text as google authentication is always encrypted

e.g: In the screenshot provided its client1.google.com is a google server.

Please be informed that you would need to perform such tests only on authorized websites , In a scenario of this request which has come up during recording, please feel free to delete it